# Testing Interface with spyOn in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I am new to Angular, however I want to test my first implementation. I defined a db.json file with 2 sample students, which I serve with json-server. The app does work well, however I read that in Angular/TypeScript one does not test against samples in a server, but create Mock objects to be used with spyOn.

So I have defined in `Student.ts`

```
export interface Student {
    id: number,
    name: string;
}
```

and then I have a service `student.service.ts`

```
  addStudent(student: Student): Observable<Student> {
    return this.http.post<Student>(this.apiUrl, student, httpOptions);
  }
```

And the test file `student.service.spec.ts`

```
describe('StudentService', () => {
  let service: StudentService;
  let student: Student;


student = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'John Rambo'
}


  it('should add a student', () => {
    let studentServiceMock = 
      spyOn(service, 'addStudent')
        .and
        .returnValue(of(student));
      expect(service.addStudent(student)).toBeTruthy();
  })
```

Now it seems like a very dummy test, but what other thing should I expect()?
Even if I use `toHaveBeenCalled` I get

> Error:  : Expected a spy, but got Observable({
> _subscribe: Function }).

If I do `expect(service.addStudent(student)).toHaveSize(1);` the test pass, but I  don't know what I'm really adding in this case, since I need to build a Student by hand first?

Comment: Where do you define `student`? or are you just passing around `undefined`?

Comment: `let student: Student;` third line in student.service.spec.ts??

Comment: You declare it, but you don't instantiate it. It's undefined at that point.

Comment: Thanks, I added a student, however I still wonder what's the proper way to test for a match or equal in the expect().

Comment: It's one way. You could also use the HttpTestingController .

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you are trying to test the wrong thing
your service returns an 'observable' type

you could try to directly test the 'subscribe' in return from your call

```
it('should add a student', () => {
     let studentServiceMock = spyOn(service,'addStudent').and.returnValue(of(student));
     service.addStudent(student).subscribe( result => {
       expect(result).toBe(student);
     }
})
```

in this specific case you are testing the actual return of the service